# How to localize notifications with android_alarm_manager

Tags: flutter, localization, android-alarms, localnotification, flutter-local-notification

I am building a Flutter app and want to show local notifications. Therefore, I use the android_alarm_manager plugin to schedule the notifications and then display them with flutter_local_notifications.

The problem is that the app should be localized and thus the notifications. This requires calling

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)!.myLocalizedString
```

which in return requires accessing context. To my knowledge, context is neither accessible in the main() function, nor in initState() or directly in the callback function invoked by android_alarm_manager.

Misusing the build method to access context seems bad practice for me. So how to do this best?

Comment: Where in your code do you handle events from `android_alarm_manager`?

Comment: In a public method that does not belong to any class. This is a requirement stated in the android_alarm_manager documentation so that it can be accessed from outside the app.